# Passing data between two Ethereum networks

Tags: contract-design, quorum, permissioned-chain

I have some IoT(Internet of things) nodes sharing the received data from sensors with each others. I partitioned them to 2 permissioned networks:
Network 1 includes: X,Y,Z nodes trusting each other,for example,.
Network 2 includes: M,N,O nodes trusting each other. 
In addition to overall smart contract for each network 1 and 2,

Can I write an individual contract which is special for each node of network( a smart contract for each node)  for doing particular act in special time, such as sending data to the another node of another network in special time?
Regards,
Siamak

Answer (score 1):

Polkadot protocol is planning to address some of the interblockchain issues.

You can see early work here:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridge

However the current release supports only inter-blockchain ERC-20 token transfers. Arbitrary message passing, like data related to IP addresses and such, is not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Mikko's valid answer: in general blockchains can't communicate between each other. So you'll need some sort of bridge - be it automated or manual.

In any case you need some sort of trusted entity between the two blockchains. Neither blockchain's trust model can extend outside the blockchain so the same trust would apply outside. They may be secure internally but you'll have to established some special model of trust (a bridge) for the blockchains to "trust" each other.